# Android interfacing

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I always have this problem of `java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not execute method of the activity`. I was planning to perform an android component event (ex. Button event - indicating the number of times this button was clicked). Here's the code snippet for this problem:

```
interface Selection {
    public void clicked();
}
public class ParentClass extends FragmentActivity {
    // fTabs : FragmentTabHost
    // tabs : Map<String, Selection>    
    private void initialize() {
        // fistFrag : FirstChildClass = new FirstChildClass()
        // secondFrag : SecondChildClass = new SecondChildClass()
        tabs.put("first", firstFrag);
        tabs.put("second", secondFrag);
        fTabs.add(fTab.newTabSpec("first").setTitle("First"), firstFrag.getClass(), null)
        fTabs.add(fTab.newTabSpec("second").setTitle("Second"), secondFrag.getClass(), null)
    }
    @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       tabs.get(fTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()).clicked();
   }
}    
public class FirstChildClass extends Fragment implements Selection {
        // data : TextView
        // hit : int = 0
        @Override
        public void clicked() {
            data.setText(String.format("Hit Count: %d", ++hit));
        }
    }
public class SecondChildClass extends Fragment implements Selection {
        // data : TextView
        // hit : int = 0
        @Override
        public void clicked() {
            data.setText(String.format("Hit Count: %d", ++hit));
        }
    }
```

I've tried to assure of `clicked()` works view interfacing approach by invoking a message on `Logcat` and it worked but when I used `Button` the error above always prompts me. I've checked if `data` is null and it returned `true`. I am a little bit confused, I've tried to check nullity of `data` from the `Activity` methods is returns `false` but when I access any method override by an interface it always return `true`. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I think your tabs should be a Map<String, ChildClass> because now you're only referencing to the interface (selection) without implementing it into an activity

Comment: I have updated my question regarding how I create object of `ChildClass`.

Comment: @NAYOSO: sorry i've just understood your comment, the idea is that there are different classes other than `ChildClass` to be added in `fTabHost`.

Comment: could you post more code? if it's very long you can try to post it here -> https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Can you post the full exception?

Comment: Could you explain where data is declared and initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way my friend told me to solve this problem. Using `getSupportFragmentManager`. He told me also that creating an `Activity` or `Fragment` using its constructor isn't applicable on the Android platform. So I switched by to the conventional way of adding tabs to `FragmentTabHost`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //tabs.get(fTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()).clicked();
    ((Selection) getSupportFragmentManager().findByFragmentByTag(fTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()).clicked();
}
```